# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error for cross domain image uploading

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, cross-domain, image-uploading, blueimp

****Use Case:****I am using [jquery/ajax uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for cross domain image upload.I have set up a demo for cross domain upload of images using PHP.

****Issue:****When I upload images from one domain to other(I have the server folder with PHP files on other domain) the original image gets uploaded but,the thumbnail doesn't upload(or is not created) and I get an error for Access-Control-Allow-Origin

I have kept the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** parameter in UploadHandler.php as **'*'**.My GET request doesn't give me the error but when I upload I see a Option request(which works right) and a POST request which produces the error.

**Reasearch/Study:** I went through a few question and tried to go through GIT issues for this plugin and they suggest that adding the **'*'** in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter should do the trick like this(The php file comes along with the plugin).Rest of the settings have been kept to default in the js files.

```
     'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
        'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
        'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
            'OPTIONS',
            'HEAD',
            'GET',
            'POST',
            'PUT',
            'PATCH',
            'DELETE'
        ),
```

Please suggest any solution that would help in this scenario.

Attached an image to clearify the error!!Please suggest any solutions.
[image]

![Headers for failed options request][3]

**Update:**

```
 'image_versions' => array(
            // Uncomment the following version to restrict the size of
            // uploaded images:

            'original' => array(
                'max_width' => 1920,
                'max_height' => 1200,
                'jpeg_quality' => 95
            ),

            // Uncomment the following to create medium sized images:

            '800x600' => array(
                'max_width' => 800,
                'max_height' => 600,
                'jpeg_quality' => 80
            ),

            '150x150' => array(
                'max_width' => 80,
                'max_height' => 80
            )
        )
```

This is the array I am using for creating the cropped forms of the uploaded image.When I don't pass the array I get the success headers in response,but when I do,I get the `Access-Control-Origin-Error`.When I check the server logs,I get a `Headers already sent error`.(**The PHP script I am using is the same as with the plugin.Present in `server/php` folder**)

Comment: Did you check firing the `OPTIONS` to the server and see what it returns?

Comment: The `OPTIONS` request returns me the ok 200 message!!I have updated the image with all the three requests!!

Comment: Please, show us headers of a failed request (single click on a line at the Network tab)

Comment: @Салман #Olegas Added an image with the headers!

Comment: @sachlearner — The *status* of the OPTIONS response doesn't really matter, its the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for it that does.

Comment: `the original image gets uploaded but,the thumbnail doesn't` Howz that possible! both hitting the same server!

Comment: @Quentin Yes I understand that,but I have kept it to `*` and still I get the error.FYI,the image is uploaded,but only a single instance of the image and neither the thumbnail is created nor images with other dimensions that I have added!

Comment: @Салман Even I am stumbled on it!!It works as expected on my local network but the POST on server doesn't give a response.Not sure what could be the reason?Does it TIME OUT due to any reason?How can I debug it?

Comment: @Салман It's uploaded but still I get the error! Even that I am not able to figure out why?Is there any configuration issue that might be causing trouble?(I think it shouldn't as the `ORIGIN` error is thrown by the browser as far as I know).Please help stuck badly

Comment: `the image is uploaded,but only a single instance`. Are you uploading two images? if yes, why not generating the thumbnail from the original image on server-side?

Comment: Yes I guess the plugin does the same(creates thumbnail server side) @Салман !I am uploading a single image at a time. I am studying the code,hopefully I get through! :) Thank you!

Comment: @Olegas #Салман I have updated the question.I am generating the thumbnails after uploading itself!